# Copy the data from the selected cell (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, copy

I have a Swipe left/right in UITableViewCellю

How can I make it so that I can copy the data from the selected cell?

I tried to use it:

```
let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text
```

But the app crashes

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?{
    let closeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Close", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Copy")

            //let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            //UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text

        success(true)
    })
    closeAction.title = "Copy"
    closeAction.backgroundColor = .purple

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [closeAction])
}
```

Comment: What is reason for crash?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I'm not sure that I copied the correct one  -  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIConcretePasteboard setString:]: Argument is not an object of type NSString [(null)]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text
```

With:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.textLabel?.text
```

because you are using `tableView` in `cellForRowAt` method. So I replaced `table` with `tableView` and in second line Replace `detailTextLabel` with `textLabel`.

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string from your array of data like this:

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = myData[indexPath.row]
```

Insted of this:

```
let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text
```